# Prepared statement with string interpolation fails with syntax errors

Tags: php, postgresql, prepared-statement

I'm trying to use prepared statements to do a simple insert with PHP and Postgres. So far, I've done this:

```
<?php
$conn_string = "host=localhost port=5432"; // plus us/pw
$dbconn = pg_connect($conn_string); 

$table  = 'business_primary_category';
$column = 'primary_category';
$tag = 'restuarant';


// Prepare a query for execution
$result = pg_prepare($dbconn, "my_query", 'SELECT * FROM $table WHERE $column = $1');

// Execute the prepared query.  Note that it is not necessary to escape
// the string "Joe's Widgets" in any way
$result = pg_execute($dbconn, "my_query", array("$tag"));

?>
```

I've taken it basically from the page on php.net, and can't figure out what I've done wrong. Do I need to install a library to use it or something. Thanks!

These are the errors I get:

```
Warning: pg_prepare() [function.pg-prepare]: Query failed: ERROR: syntax error at or near "$" at character 15 in /home/url    **......**   pdo.php on line 11

Warning: pg_execute() [function.pg-execute]: Query failed: ERROR: prepared statement "my_query" does not exist in /home/url    **......**   pdo.php on line 15

Warning: pg_execute() [function.pg-execute]: Query failed: ERROR: prepared statement "my_query" does not exist in /home/url    **......**   pdo.php on line 18
```

Comment: You probably need double quotes around your query for your variables to be evaluated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want your variables to be interpolated, then you need to use double quotes; else PHP treats it as a string literal. Try:

```
$result = pg_prepare($dbconn, "my_query", "SELECT * FROM $table WHERE $column = $1");
```

Comment: hi. thanks! that definitely cleared up the error. neat! I was worried that I had to install some sort of PDO package. Is that for something else?

Comment: PDO is a library to access databases - it would replace your existing `pg_*` functions. PDO is recommended because it makes it easy to write more secure code - it supports prepared statements and bound parameters, which the basic `mysql_` functions don't. Since you've already using those, there's no need to re-write everything in PDO for security's sake.

Comment: Ah, great. so just to be clear. These user suppled strings are definitely sufficiently escaped now that i'm using this prepared statement `stuff`?

Comment: If the only user-based input is in your variables, then yes, you're secure if you pass those in as bound parameters. If you're using user-generated content directly in your SQL, you're not - in your code, if `$table` or `$column` are user-generated, you could still have issues, because they're going straight in the query and not being sanitized at all.

Comment: Oh. how should I sanitize them? Just with a `real_escape_string`? I've heard that's on the way out. Should I consider this switchover to PDO? is that just for mysql, or does postgre have it as well built into php? Thanks for all the help!

Comment: PDO is, I think, database independent. I don't believe that it will give you any benefit if you need to include user-specified tables and columns - I don't think either can be included as variables in prepared statements. You can whitelist, though - create an array of allowed values, and check that the variables you're passed are in that array.

Comment: U saved me, It works on golang to. I should use double quote instead of  `. The queries are interpolated when I saw it on general_log

Answer (score 2):

First thing that jumps out... Use double quotes on `'SELECT * FROM $table WHERE $column = $1'`.